# Why did Moshe want to go into Eretz Yisroel

Tags: vaeschanan, parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu

The famous question of the Gemara (סוטה יד, א)is why did Moshe want to go into Eretz Yisroel did he want to eat of its fruit? The answer would seem to be simple he wanted to do the Mitzva of living in Israel?

Comment: Why do you assume that living in Israel is a mitsvah?

Comment: I remember learning that the Spies lied about what and who they saw in Israel because they hoped that would extend their time learning Torah with Moses by not having to concern themselves about normal, everyday life. They would, in essence, remain on a higher spiritual level. . I thought Moses wanted  to enter Israel in order the fulfill  the commandment to enter and work the land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reb Yackov in His **Emes Liyackov** says that the **Tashbetz** says that the Mitzvah of living in Israel is only for those who have a Chelek of Eretz Yisroel since Moshe was A Levi He had None hence he had no Mitzvah of living in Eretz Yisroel!!!!!!

Comment: Exactly where does he say this?

Comment: This answer is actually given in Chemdas Yisroal (pg.13) by Rav Meir Dan. The concept challenged in Piskei Teshuva  (Petrekov) 248 pg. 75.

Answer (score 3):

The Meshekh Hokhmah (Deuteronomy 11:31) answers that before the land was apportioned into tribes, the mitsvah of settling the land of Israel included Transjordan. Accordingly, Moshe already fulfilled this mitsvah.

Comment: It should be noted that this is an incredibly weak question. R. Simlai never asked this as an actual question, rather, the Talmud quotes "darash R. Simlai"; this was a rhetorical question.